# JavaScript: Parse jsonstring

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json string returned by a C# razor page method as follows:

```
var data = 
{"Transactions":"[{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T10:41:26.318\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"e1ddc1ac-0c0c-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"309999\",\"Plate#\":\"\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"4\",\"AVC Class\":\"4\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"072\",\"Lane\":\"41\"},{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T10:53:26.229\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"7c5dccbe-0c0e-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"309119\",\"Plate#\":\"JSON06\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"4\",\"AVC Class\":\"4\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"072\",\"Lane\":\"41\"},{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T13:05:26.17\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"fb707240-0c20-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"377159\",\"Plate#\":\"470E03\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"2\",\"AVC Class\":\"2\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"040\",\"Lane\":\"2\"}]","ReturnCode":0,"ReturnString":"Succesful"}
```

How do I extract transactions in my javascript? Here's my current code:

```
var _transactions = [];
var allData= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
_transactions = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + allData.Transactions + ")"));
```

This code works fine for a small number of 'transactions', but doesn't work for thousands of records.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Not sure why there's an `eval` here; `data.Transactions` is already a string and can be parsed as-is. Do you mean the string is `'var data = {"..."}'`? That doesn't line up w/ the `parseJSON(data)`.

Comment: `var transactions = JSON.parse(data.Transactions)`

Comment: Transactions is a string.

Comment: That's what `JSON.parse()` does; parses JSON strings to objects. If you have a JSON string containing thousands of records and you say it's running too slow are you asking for a faster JSON parser? On a client (e.g., browser) or server? If client, not like you can do anything meaningful with thousands of records anyway--that's what pagination is for.

Comment: That's why I'm parsing it to an array ... which from your question seems what you want.

Comment: You have a JSON string in data - right.  Then you parse the whole thing to get an object then you take one property of the object and convert that back to json?  If this is very slow (I'm not surprised), you might like to try to work on the string direct.  Eg the start would be let i=data.indexOf("{\"transactions\":")  Finding the end point at position j is only a bit more challenging but doable then your transactions json is data.substring (i,j).  That should be very fast even for a multi-megabyte string.

Comment: @dave11022 Pretty please with sugar on top, do not suggest to parse JSON with some self-hacked parser ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why you are using eval and even why jQuery

Here is plain JS

```js
const transactions = JSON.parse(data.Transactions)
console.log(transactions)
// example of getting the item values - use [""] for strings with spaces
transactions.forEach(transaction => console.log(transaction["Transponder ID"]))
```

```html
<script>
const data = {"Transactions":"[{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T10:41:26.318\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"e1ddc1ac-0c0c-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"309999\",\"Plate#\":\"\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"4\",\"AVC Class\":\"4\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"072\",\"Lane\":\"41\"},{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T10:53:26.229\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"7c5dccbe-0c0e-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"309119\",\"Plate#\":\"JSON06\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"4\",\"AVC Class\":\"4\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"072\",\"Lane\":\"41\"},{\"BatchID\":\"814C87D9-7037-4E66-97EC-5861D2712997\",\"BatchOpenStatus\":\"Y\",\"Time\":\"2021-09-02T13:05:26.17\",\"recType\":\"Trip\",\"RevisionNum\":0,\"ID\":\"fb707240-0c20-11ec-b55b-e2b9dfec84c8\",\"Payment Type\":\"2\",\"Tag Agency\":\"0046\",\"Transponder ID\":\"377159\",\"Plate#\":\"470E03\",\"State\":\"\",\"Type\":\"PAS\",\"Class\":\"2\",\"AVC Class\":\"2\",\"VehSpeed\":\" \",\"TagStatus\":\"0\",\"TagClass\":\"2\",\"Plaza\":\"040\",\"Lane\":\"2\"}]","ReturnCode":0,"ReturnString":"Succesful"}</script>
```

Comment: I have a DevExpress DataGrid that I'm binding the dataSource to the Transactions Array. I can't seem to be able to do it. I'll try DevExpress support. Thank you for your solutions.